# Regarding Oracle Regexp_Replace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, regexp-replace

I've a string like "Vinoth^Vinoth Karthick Vinoth^Vinoth^Vinoth" delimited by "^". I would like to replace only Vinoth by XXX.

```
I/P String : Vinoth^Vinoth Karthick Vinoth^Vinoth^Vinoth
Expected output : XXX^Vinoth Karthick Vinoth^XXX^XXX
```

Please suggest how to do this using Regexp_replace or any other function in ORACLE SQL Statement.

Comment: you should be able to replace the string including the delimiter with a new string also including the delimiter with REPLACE.  you may also feel compelled to use the REGEX replace option if your pattern is more complex.

Comment: Which one do you want to changed `^Vinoth` or `Vinoth`as pattern string? Since, i think Expected output should be `XXX^Vinoth Karthick XXX^Vinoth^Vinoth` or `VinothXXX Karthick VinothXXXXXX` ...

Comment: I/P String : Vinoth^Vinoth Karthick Vinoth^Vinoth^Vinoth
Expected output : XXX^Vinoth Karthick Vinoth^XXX^XXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double up the delimiter `^` characters and wrap the string in delimiter `^` characters so that each element has its own distinct leading and trailing delimiter then you can just replace `^Vinoth^` with `^XXX^` and reverse the doubling of the delimiters and trim the leading and trailing delimiters:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/290)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TRIM(
         '^' FROM
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
             '^' ||
             REPLACE(
               'Vinoth^Vinoth Karthick Vinoth^Vinoth^Vinoth',
               '^',
               '^^'
             )
             || '^',
             '^Vinoth^',
             '^XXX^'
           ),
           '^^',
           '^'
         )
       ) AS replaced
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/290/0)**:

```
|                           REPLACED |
|------------------------------------|
| XXX^Vinoth Karthick Vinoth^XXX^XXX |
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Vinoth^Vinoth Karthick Vinoth^Vinoth^Vinoth' from dual),
  3  inter as
  4    (select regexp_substr(replace(col, '^', ':'), '[^:]+', 1, level) col,
  5            level lvl
  6     from test
  7     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '\^') + 1
  8    )
  9  select listagg(regexp_replace(col, '^Vinoth$', 'XXX'), '^')
 10    within group (order by lvl) result
 11  from inter;

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

XXX^Vinoth Karthick Vinoth^XXX^XXX

SQL>
```

Comment: This fails on `Vinoth^Vinoth Karthick :Vinoth^Vinoth^Vinoth`

Comment: And probably on quite a few other examples, @MT0, but that's not what the OP said to be the input.

Comment: OP wanted to replace an entire element of a `^` delimited string - you are changing the delimiter (when you do not need to) and it is now treating it as a delimited list where the delimiter is either `^` or `:`, which is incorrect. Change the regular expression to search for non-caret characters and you won't have the problem but just dismissing the issue out of hand as it does not match the narrow example the OP gave rather than the intent of the question is disingenuous and does not help future users with a similar problem.